# Unable to fetch the json value by using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

This is my file structure, I would Like to access Subscription base on the value of "Name"

```
{                                                                    
 "Topics": 
 [
     {
         "Name": "topic1",
         "Subscription": "sub1"
     },
     {
         "Name": "topic2",
         "Subscription": "sub2"
     }
 ]

}

$json = Get-Content 'path' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$subscriptions=$json.Topics.Subscription|Where Name -EQ "topic1"
```

I'm getting the Name by executing following command

```
$json.Topics.Name
    topic1
    topic2
$json.Topics.Subscriptions
    sub1
    sub2
```

But not sure how to keep this in where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$json = @'
{
    "Topics":
    [
        {
            "Name": "topic1",
            "Subscription": "sub1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "topic2",
            "Subscription": "sub2"
        }
    ]

}
'@

$objectFromJson  = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$objectFromJson.Topics | Where-Object Name -eq 'topic1'
```

The above yields:

```
Name   Subscription
----   ------------
topic1 sub1
```

If you would like to output only the `.Subscription` property value, simply use
`($objectFromJson.Topics | Where-Object Name -eq 'topic1').Subscription`

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$json.Topics.Subscription`

This extracts the *values* of the `Subscription` properties, which are mere *strings* (`"sub1"` and `"sub2"`), which don't have a `.Name` property, so your `Where Name -EQ "topic1"` filter matches nothing.